# javascript regex verify a variable then capture that variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought I'd rewrite this and add a bit of context (more so it'll be easier to explain to me) .

Basicaly I'm capturing the back/forward buttons with the popstate event like so :

```
 window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) { 


     curstate = window.location.href ;
```

Then using a switch statement to determine what to do based on the new state :

```
     switch (curstate) {

        case 'http://mydomain.com/':

            navi('about', 200);
            break;



        case 'http://mydomain.com/resume':
            navi('resume', 200);
            break;
        };

    });
```

The problem comes when the state is mydomain.com/portfolio/-whatever-

I need a case : starts with mydomain.com/portfolio/(capture this bit of the uri) : then put the captured bit in a variable eg `currentpage = capturedbitofuri` .

Comment: `/^mydomain\.com\/portfolio\/(.*)$/` Captured after it. What do you mean by pop?

Comment: Not as in `array_pop`, he just means "put it in a variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// returns an array on success or null on failure
var match = /^mydomain\.com\/portfolio\/(.*)/.exec(str); 
if (match) {
   // match[1] contains the group (.*), which is everything after the prefix
   return match[1]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Dor , I've got the following set up like so `curstate = window.location.href ;
   
   var match = /^mydomain\.com\/portfolio\/(.*)/.exec(curstate); 
   console.log(match);
   if (match) {
           // match[1] contains the group (.*), which is everything after the prefix
          console.log(match[1]); 
         }; ` but all I get is a null from match.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward: `/^mydomain\.com\/portfolio\/(.*)/`

The `/` characters must be escaped, as we're using `/` as the delimiter for the pattern.

`^` at the start of the pattern indicates that the string must start with "mydomain...".

At the end, the `.*` means "anything" and the `( )` around it means "capture this in a match".

As for using it, have a read over [regex in JS 101](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml), it'll give you a good introduction to regex :)

Comment: And capturing what's after it?

Comment: @Joe In JavaScript, a RegExp is surrounded by slashes (`/`). Literal `/`s have to be escaped: `\/`.

Comment: True :) Good catch, dropped into PHP mode there haha

Comment: ok (sorry this is a bit new to me) , i need it in too parts , one part to check it it starts with that and I use the variable within the if statement .

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml - give that a quick read @FrankAstin, it's a good basic 101 for regex in JS

Comment: Thanks for the link Joe . I've updated the question , which will hopefully make it easier to explain to me how to get this working .

Comment: @Joe This is what I've got so far : `curstate = window.location.href ;
   var reg = /^mydomain\.com\/portfolio\/(.*)/;
   regtest = reg.test(curstate);
   console.log(regtest);` This just returns nulls though....

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regex. All you need to wrap your head around is .indexOf and .substring.

```
if (curstate === 'http://mydomain.com/') {

    navi('about', 200);

} else if (curstate === 'http://mydomain.com/resume')

    navi('resume', 200);

} else if (curstate.indexOf('http://mydomain.com/portfolio') > -1) {
    var base = 'http://mydomain.com/portfolio';
    portfoliosection = curstate.substr(base.length + 1, curstate.length);
}
```

Comment: I got there slightly differently , but this looks like a neater option . Thanks Devin .

Comment: yeah I like that you don't have to rack your brain (or anyone else working with your code) on figuring out regular expressions.